# Wine Cannot build a 32-bit program error

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, wine

So I've been getting this problem (as seen below) on my CentOS 7 (64-bit) server when I try and configure wine with png with the following code:

```
./configure --with-png
```

I need this to run a specific server for a game called Mount & Blade Warband.
Because when I run the server i get this:

```
err:wincodecs:PngEncoder_CreateInstance Trying to save PNG picture, but PNG support is not compiled in.
fixme:ole:CoCreateInstance no instance created for interface {00000103-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94} of class {27949969-876a-41d7-9447-568f6a35a4dc}, hres is 0x80004005
```

I have looked at this post:

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=44897

They said that the following code should fix it:

```
yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

But it didn't, atleast not for me. I`m still getting the following error over and over:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for cpp... cpp
checking for ld... ld
checking whether gcc -m32 works... no
configure: error: Cannot build a 32-bit program, you need to install 32-bit development libraries.
```

Comment: This article might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/123273/installing-wine-1-5-configure-error-cannot-build-a-32-bit-program-you-need-t

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, I had to run this code to install 32-bit devolpment libraries in order to do --with-png. The code came from this post:
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=49542

Code:

```
yum install glibc-devel.i686 dbus-devel.i686 freetype-devel.i686 pulseaudio-     libs-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 mesa-libGLU-devel.i686 libICE-devel.i686 libXext-devel.i686 libXcursor-devel.i686 libXi-devel.i686 libXxf86vm-devel.i686 libXrender-devel.i686 libXinerama-devel.i686 libXcomposite-devel.i686 libXrandr-devel.i686 mesa-libGL-devel.i686 mesa-libOSMesa-devel.i686 libxml2-devel.i686 libxslt-devel.i686 zlib-devel.i686 gnutls-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 sane-backends-devel.i686 libv4l-devel.i686 libgphoto2-devel.i686 libexif-devel.i686 lcms2-devel.i686 gettext-devel.i686 isdn4k-utils-devel.i686 cups-devel.i686 fontconfig-devel.i686 gsm-devel.i686 libjpeg-turbo-devel.i686 pkgconfig.i686 libtiff-devel.i686 unixODBC.i686 openldap-devel.i686 alsa-lib-devel.i686 audiofile-devel.i686 freeglut-devel.i686 giflib-devel.i686 gstreamer-devel.i686 gstreamer-plugins-base-devel.i686 libXmu-devel.i686 libXxf86dga-devel.i686 libieee1284-devel.i686 libpng-devel.i686 librsvg2-devel.i686 libstdc++-devel.i686 libusb-devel.i686 unixODBC-devel.i686 qt-devel.i686
```